# PreWarmCache for MVC Application with Stopwatch Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I used the information from the article ["Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) to create a background task that runs on an infinite loop. Ultimately, this program is going to be consuming a REST API to get data from a remote web site and insert records into my database. For the time being, I am just doing a basic insert.

```
public class PreWarmCache : System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient
{
    private static BackgroundTaskContext db = new BackgroundTaskContext();
    private static Timer _timer;

    public void Preload(string[] parameters)
    {
        // Perform initialization and cache loading logic here...
        try
        {
            var doStuff = new DoStuff();
            doStuff.DoStuffName = "Test from PRELOAD INIT " + DateTime.Now;
            db.DoStuffs.Add(doStuff);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        var timeInMilliseconds = 0;
        _timer = new Timer(Callback, null, timeInMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);

    }

    public static void Callback(Object state)
    {
        var timeInMilliseconds = 5000;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        watch.Start();

        // Update the database
        try
        {
            var doStuff = new DoStuff();
            doStuff.DoStuffName = "Test from CALLBACK " + DateTime.Now;
            db.DoStuffs.Add(doStuff);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        _timer.Change(Math.Max(0, timeInMilliseconds - watch.ElapsedMilliseconds), Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I've been keeping an eye on the Auto-Start feature but haen't gotten a chance to use it much. Any idea how it does with [these limitations of IIS applications](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55156/10775)?

Comment: Not yet. I am just trying to get the REST API code working. Debugging is difficult. I am not sure how to debug this once deployed to IIS and the code does not seem to be working. I know I can attach a worker process. But, it's not really helping me.

Comment: heavy logging always helps me in that scenario.

Comment: you dont have to use IProcessHostPreloadClient , u want data to be prefetched every 5 min. so create a window service and fetch the data , insert into you db

Answer (score 2):

There are some things that you could have done better certainly.

My first pick is the class name `DoStuff`. Please try pick a more meaningful name like `Action` or `Task`.

In this class you seem to be appending the current time to the property `DoStuffName` (which should also be renamed accordingly). You could pass the name in the constructor and append the current time instead, like:

```
public class Task{
   public Task(string name){
      Name = name + " " + DateTime.Now;
   }
   public string Name{
     get; private set;
   }  
}
```

You also seem to have one of the most evil bad practises of programming - the empty catch block. Be sure to, at least, log the exception somewhere.

Comment: You should preferably throw the exception again, even if you log it. Unless you've handled the situation that caused the exception, you should rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 2):

**Naming**

I don't like underscore notation, but it's regularly debated and is mostly a matter for personal preference, however everybody agrees that if you pick a naming scheme, stick with it.

```
private static BackgroundTaskContext db = new BackgroundTaskContext();
private static Timer _timer;
```

It should be `_db` or `timer`. Not both.

**Static**

Your use of static is confusing here. Do you really only want one timer and background task context for every instance of `PreWarmCache`? If you only want one instance, make it so, do not allow multiples and then have them all overwriting each other.

There also seems to be a case where calling `Preload` multiple times will just reset the timer and only call callback with the state from the last preload call.

**Var**

Mostly, you're pretty good for using `var` correctly, but you don't use it consistently.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
```

Should be

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
```